# how give from html textarea line String java in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Is such html code page jsp?

```
<form action="">
<div align="center"><textarea name="" cols="50" rows="4">welcome to my program</textarea></div>
</form>
```

if write in this textarea line. How the line translate in object String in servlet?

I'm know such the way.

```
  <form action="perform_action.jsp" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>
```

perform_action.jsp:

```
if ( <all_ок> ) { 
    Sample.task(); 
}
```

may way do on the one page jsp?
sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the form action point to the servlet URL as definied in `<url-pattern>` in `web.xml` and give the input elements a name.

```
<form action="servleturl" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The submitted content will be available in `doPost()` method of servlet as request parameter where you use the name of the input element as parameter name.

```
String text = request.getParameter("text");
```

#### See also:

- [Servlets tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains hello world example and useful tutorial links

Comment: That's the simplest solution I've seen on Servlet. +1.

Comment: @The: so, more detailed solutions don't deserve a vote? Geesh.